# PHP validating user input data step by step

Tags: php, if-statement

I am fairly new to PHP, for now I am having to write small programs in PHP while my company finds a suitable programmer.

I have written a program which uses form data (Name, E-mail, mobile number etc) and then checks if the entered data is valid. My code work just fine but they don't follow any procedure (i.e. it checks all the validation). I want it to first check one condition (like E-mail) if its valid, then only check the next condition (phone number). If its invalid, then return some error message & stop going through rest of the code.

I've tried bunch of things but none has worked, here's the sample code

```
<?php include("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/dbconnection.php"); ?>
 
<?php
 //I've done this in main.php page but also had to do it in functions.php page too...
 $First_Name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $Last_Name = $_POST['last_name'];
 $Phone_Number = $_POST['phone_number'];
 $E_Mail = $_POST['email'];
 $User_ID = $_POST['user_id'];
?> 
 
<?php $user_id_validation = validate_user_id($User_ID); ?>
<?php $phone_number_validation = validate_phone_number(); ?>
<?php $all_fields_validation = validate_all_fields(); ?>

<?php 
 //This is dbconnection.php page
 define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
 define("DB_USER", "root");
 define("DB_PASS", "some_password");
 define("DB_NAME", "some_db");

  
   $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME); //This $connection has been used as global in function.php 
   
   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . 
    mysqli_connect_error() . 
    " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
  );
   }
?>
<?php
 //This is functions.php
 function validate_user_id($User_ID) {
  global $connection;
  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$User_ID'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
  $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($num_row == 1) {
  $User_ID = $num_row['user_id'];
  echo "user verification passed! ";
  } else {
   echo "You are not authorized to perform this action! ";
  }
  return false;
 }
 
 function validate_phone_number() {
  $Phone_Number = $_POST['phone_number'];
  $check_phone_number = substr($phone_number, 0, -7); //Take first 3 digits of phone number to validate if its standard phone number
    
  if (strlen($Phone_Number) != 10) {
   echo "Invalid Phone Number";
  } elseif ($check_phone_number === "740") {
   echo "Phone Number is valid ";
  } else {
   echo "Invalid Phone Number, please check again! ";
  }
 }
  
 function validate_all_fields() {
  $First_Name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $Last_Name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $Phone_Number = $_POST['phone_number'];
  $E_Mail = $_POST['email'];
  $User_ID = $_POST['user_id'];
  
  if (!empty($E_Mail)
  && !empty($Phone_Number) 
  && !empty($First_Name)
  && !empty($Last_Name))
  
  ) {
   echo "All fields entered, you can proceed. ";
  } else { 
   echo "E_Mail, Phone Number, First Name and Last Name must be entered!"; 
  }
 }
 // Database Insertion
 function Insert_Into_Table () {
  global $connection;
  $First_Name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $Last_Name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $Phone_Number = $_POST['phone_number'];
  $E_Mail = $_POST['email'];
  $User_ID = $_POST['user_id'];
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO some_tbl(User_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Phone_Number, E_Mail)
    VALUES ('$User_ID', '$First_Name', '$Last_Name', '$Phone_Number', '$E_Mail')";
  
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
   
 }
 
?>
```

Comment: use `if(){.....}elseif(){...}else{..final..}`

Comment: "I've tried bunch of things" we have no idea what those things are hence it is impossible to help. Also imho what you are trying to do will cause a pretty bad user experience, because the user will only know 1 fields is not filled in correctly and onyl submit he finds out there are other fields invalid.

Comment: You can use both PHP and Javascript Validation. Please check this, [Php/javascript email form and validation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680406/php-javascript-email-form-and-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Im not sure whether you want this or not..

```
if(!is_email($email))
{
    echo 'Invalid email!!';
    exit();
}
elseif(!is_phone($phone)) 
{
    echo 'Invalid Phone!!';
    exit();
}
else {
   //success code
}
```

Then create a function named `is_email()` and write the validation code there and return `true` if it is in email format otherwise return `false`

```
 is_email($email)
 {
     //validation code
 }
```

Comment: You are a star! It worked, Thanks a lot, you have no idea how much I can enjoy my holiday tomorrow !!!

Comment: @ys1458 If this answer was helpfull for your question, plz mark it as its answer.. :-)